# Max value for initial term of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, maxima-minima

This is a nice math-contest problem. I was thinking it a few days ago, but I didn't get anything.

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\ge1}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n$ we have $n|a_n$ and $|a_n-a_{n+1}|\le4$. What is the maximum value that $a_1$ takes?

It is clear that for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, since $1|m$ then we can take $a_1=m$, so the first part is satisfied.  Therefore, I think it is better to concentrate in $a_2$ than $a_1$. On the other hand, $a_{n+1}=a_n\pm k_n$ for some $k_n\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ for all $n$.

But I don't know how to combine both ideas.

Comment: I think the idea is to arrive at a sequence for which if we start generating possible next terms beginning with a given big value of $a_0$,  and we reach something like a case when $a_9$ can now only take value $45$ for eg., from which we can't proceed further

Comment: The four sequences $a_n=kn$ for $k=1,2,3,4$ all work. Suppose a particular sequence had $a_n=kn$ for $k>4$ (and some $n$). Then for $k(n+1)>a_n+4$ and $(k-1)(n+1)=a_n-(n+1-k)$, so you are stuck if $n+1-k>4$. So you might think that starting with $a_1>4$ will fail, but initially you can go down instead of up, eg $a_1=10,a_2=10,a_3=9,a_4=8,a_5=5, a_6=6,\dots$, so it is a little tricky.

Comment: $a_1=58$ works: $54,51,48,45,42,42,40,a_9=36$ and then $a_n=4n$. I got that by focussing on the highest possible value for $a_7$. The highest in the range 1-100 seems to be 42.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks to all

Comment: @sinbadh Feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Dylan done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is $\alpha_n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n=n\alpha_n$. Thus $4\ge|(n+1)\alpha_{n+1}-n\alpha_n|...(*)$ for all $n$. Now, for $n\ge 4$, it is easy to chech that $\alpha_{n+1}\le \alpha_n$. So $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\ge4}$ is eventually constant. That is, there is $k\ge4$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha_n=\alpha$ for $n\ge k$. Putting $n=k$ in $(*)$ we get $\alpha\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Lert $N=\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,:\,n\ge9,\alpha_m=\alpha\mbox{ for all }m\ge n\}$. It is easy to see that $N$ exists, and $\alpha_{N-1}\neq \alpha$. Now, in $(*)$ put $n+1=N$, so $4\ge|N\alpha_{N}-(N-1)\alpha_{N-1}|=|N\alpha-(N-1)\alpha_{N-1}|$. That is $-4+N\alpha\le(N-1)\alpha_{N-1}\le4+N\alpha...(**)$.\

If $N>9$, since $\alpha\le4$, then $N-\alpha>5$, so $N\alpha+N-\alpha-1>N\alpha+4$. Therefore, by $(**)$ we have $(N-1)(\alpha+1)>N\alpha+4\ge(N-1)\alpha_{N-1}$. Thus $\alpha_{N-1}<\alpha+1$. In the same way, we obtain $\alpha-1<\alpha_{N-1}$, so $\alpha_{N-1}=\alpha$, which contradicts definition of $N$.

We conclude $N=9$, so $\alpha_n=\alpha$ for all $n\ge9$. That is $a_n=\alpha n$ for all $n\ge9$, and since $\alpha=1,2,3,4$, then $a_9=9,18,27,36$.

Now, going down we conclude that $58$ is the desired value.